# Google maps in production

Tags: android, google-maps

Detailed procedure to use google maps in production.
Android studio google maps activity working properly in debug mode.
When app deployed in play store, maps are not showing.

Update : I have solved this issue by myself.This question can be seen as a reference for others.

Answer (score 2):

For release, you need to create a release mode certificate [follow steps to get release mode certificate under RELEASE CERTIFICATE section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup).

Comment: along with certificate we need to add 2 permissions.

Comment: i agree but the question was asked to solve a different problem plus all additional details are provided in the link, anyway nice effort  keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

you should create API KEY  for the production also before uploading it into play store.

Generally there are two keys debug key and release key. while signing app, you want to use release key. For that you want to compare that with signed apk

Step 1:

Say for example your apk name is A and you are signing and creating a keystore for A.apk ie A.keystore will be created in some drive location.Let's consider it in E drive.

step 2:

Now locate to jdk in C drive(Considering for windows and assigning C drive)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore E:\A.keystore -alias A

So it will create SHA-1 fingure print

copy and paste that in google map console, it wll generate a key.use it in maps.

Answer (score 0):

first add below permissions in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.xyz.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.xyz.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

then add key inside

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            />
```